# Externally hosted apk with minSdkVersion less than 26?

Tags: android, json, apk, targetsdkversion

I am using the google provided externallyHosted.py script to generate a JSON file for an externally hosted apk. This is no longer working because the minimumSdkVersion is less than 26 and there is no ability in the script to set the targetSdkVersion.

How can I externally host apks whilst still supporting older devices?

Comment: Minimum or target? The current absolute minimum for apps is 14.

Comment: minimumSdkVersion is 19, targetSdkVersion is 26/